# How to change the value with a variable within a for loop?

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
$extraPhoto_1 = get_field('extra_photo_1');
$extraPhoto_2 = get_field('extra_photo_2');
$extraPhoto_3 = get_field('extra_photo_3');
$extraPhoto_4 = get_field('extra_photo_4');
```

But I would like to rewrite it with a for loop, but I can't figure out how to put a variable within the value field. What I have so far is:

```
  for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
            ${'extraPhoto_' . $i} = get_field('extra_photo_ . $i');
      }
```

I've tried with an array like this:

```
    $myfiles = array();

      for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $myfiles["$extraPhoto_$i"] = get_field('extra_photo_ . $i');
      }
```

Nothing seems to fix my problem. I'v searched on the PHP website ([variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)).

Comment: `get_field('extra_photo_ '. $i);` Don't include the variable inside this `''`

Comment: @aldrin27 your code won't work due to one-space-too-much thing

Comment: @thijs-moens you should read this too: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php , esp. 2nd note there.

Comment: Ahh. Yeah. Sorry. :D just delete the space. :)

Comment: @aldrin27 Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some bug in your code which not allowing. Use `'extra_photo_'. $i` instead of `'extra_photo_. $i'`

```
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $extraPhoto_.$i = get_field('extra_photo_'. $i);
      }
```

Comment: acutally he could also do it with double quotes like: "extraphoto_$i"

Answer (score 0):

You can build an array as defined below and than just call extract($myfiles) to access them as variables.

Again your syntax for the get field is incorrect you should append $i after the quotes.

```
$myfiles = array();

  for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $myfiles["extraPhoto_".$i] = get_field('extra_photo_'.$i);
  }
extract($myfiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create dynamic variable, use below code

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
     ${'extraPhoto_'.$i} = $_POST['extra_photo_'.$i];
 }
```

if you want to assign variables to array use below code.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $myfiles["extraPhoto_$i"] = $_POST['extra_photo_'.$i];
    /// $myfiles["extraPhoto_$i"] = get_field('extra_photo_'.$i);
  }
```

and than to see if values are assign to new array or not, you can use below code.

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($myfiles);echo "</pre>";
```